# jquery date validation client side

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker and I want to validate if date is valid or not in the format

```
04/15/2014
```

User is also allowed to enter date manually. For that I am trying validation, I tried by splitting string by slashes and checking all three values, is there any simpler way.

Comment: Actually it is hard to tell @Naveen.  since you're allowing the user to enter the date manually.  How can you be sure about the `dateFormat`?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/01/client-side-validation-jquery.html or http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/52509cf3f10c60fd6600a593

Comment: @praveen dateformat I am providing as placeholder - urbz I went though one link which have demo in fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/RagGb/  it allows date - 41/41/4444

Comment: It seems you follow two types of dateformats  `mm/dd/yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question makes no mention of this plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering *all sort of validation in Date* like

1. Month limitation *(month should be within 1-12)*
2. Date limitation for the particular month *(30 and 31)*
3. Leap year validation *(Feb month should have 28 or 29)*
4. Year limitation *(4 digit validation)*

I would suggest you to look at [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/docs/) plugin.  This plugin is easy to integrate and take care of all these validation and formats.

Here is you validation method,

```
function ValidateDate(dtValue) {
    return moment(dtValue, ["MM/DD/YYYY", "MM-DD-YYYY"], true).isValid();
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/82/)

```
moment(dtValue, ["MM/DD/YYYY", "MM-DD-YYYY"], true).isValid()
```

Here,

> **dtValue** - *your date string*
>   **["MM/DD/YYYY", "MM-DD-YYYY"]** - *your list of date formats*
>   **true** - *strict validation*
>   **isValid()** - *method to check valid or not*